# How to extract image name and tag from docker-compose build output

Tags: azure, docker, shell, docker-compose, devops

I have the following script that i am hoping will build and publish to my azure container registry.

```
echo "env override file:${1}"

cd ../.devcontainer
docker compose --env-file .env --env-file $1 build

#parse image name and tag from above output here into $docker_image and $tag

docker image tag $docker_image:$tag mycontainerreg.azurecr.io/$docker_image:latest 
docker push mycontainerreg.azurecr.io/$docker_image:latest
```

After the compose comand, the last output shown is :

`=> => naming to docker.io/library/my_app:v1.0`

I would like to be able to extract the image name and tag from that output to use in the subsequent docker commands.  How can i do that?

Also what is best practice for tagging?  i tag with a version number.  but should i also re-tag as the latest version as im doing - as it would simplify downstream deploys?

for completeness my docker-compose relevant context:

```
services:
  my_app:
    container_name: my_app_${ENV}
    image: "my_app:${VERSION:-local}"
```

env files are .env, env_dev, etc:

```
VERSION=v1.0
ENV=local
USER_ID=1000
GROUP_ID=1000
USER_NAME=user1
SVC_PORT=5000
DB_PORT=5434
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the output in a variable, let it be output

```
output="=> => naming to docker.io/library/my_app:v1.0"

image_and_tag=$(echo "$output" | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}')
image_name=$(echo "$image_and_tag" | awk -F ':' '{print $1}')
image_tag=$(echo "$image_and_tag" | awk -F ':' '{print $2}')

echo "Image Name: $image_name"
echo "Image Tag: $image_tag"
```

Regarding tagging:

- Use specific version tags for production deployments (e.g., v1.0,
  v1.1).
- Use a 'latest' tag for testing, development, and internal use, but
  avoid using it for production.
- Periodically update the 'latest' tag to the latest stable version
  when appropriate, but make sure to test thoroughly before deploying
  to production.

Comment: thank you. that is my problem is how to store it as output. im not bash/scripting expert...have been trying this ```output = $(docker compose --env-file .env --env-file "${1}" build)```,  but i get the error ```".\build.sh: line 5: output: command not found"```

Comment: it looks like it was spaces around the '='.  thanks again

Comment: the issue seems to be with the space between = and output and $
try the following:
`output=$(docker compose --env-file .env --env-file "${1}" build)`

Comment: Coming back to best practices...if you  tag everything 'latest' in lower environments, don you run the risk of QA, for example, pulling an image from DEV on any docker restart in QA?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just copy the `image:` from the Compose file, and not try to parse Compose's output.  Compose's environment-variable substitution is a subset of POSIX shell syntax and you should be able to use the exact same string format in your script.

```sh
docker tag my_app:${VERSION:-local} mycontainerreg.azurecr.io/$docker_image:latest
```

When you set both `build:` and `image:` in the Compose file, the `image:` sets the name of the built image, so a better approach here might be to just set the Compose `image:` to what you want.  Then you can `docker-compose push` the built image without having to manually extract its name.

```yaml
services:
  my_app:
    build: .
    image: mycontainerreg.azurecr.io/myapp:${VERSION:-latest}
    # should not usually need container_name:
```

```sh
export VERSION=20230905
docker-compose build
docker-compose push
```

I'd suggest that tagging the image with a date stamp, source-control commit ID, or version string is a best practice.  Fixed tags like `latest` can cause some problems, particularly if you're using Kubernetes, since it becomes unclear which "latest" image you're using – if the local system already has a "latest" image then the container system usually won't check if the upstream registry has a newer one.

Comment: ah interesting..because part of your solution i ended up implementing - that is set the docker compose image to the target registry.   but i did not know about the docker-compose push option.  there also seems to be a tags property that can be used to tag in docker-compose.